# Best practice to join 2 tables with different granularity

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, visualization

I have 2 datasets below, 1 tracks the daily sales of each account. Each account can only belong to 1 city.

| Date | Region | Country | City | Account | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | NA | America | Seattle | SEA1 | 100 |
| 1/1/2023 | NA | America | Los Angeles | LOS2 | 400 |
| 1/1/2023 | NA | America | Seattle | SEA2 | 300 |
| 1/3/2023 | EU | Italy | Rome | ROM1 | 500 |
| 1/3/2023 | EU | Italy | Venice | VEN1 | 600 |

The 2nd dataset has the fixed daily goals at the city level for a whole year (we don't have the goal for accounts). However, we will have some cities that sales occur above but we don't have a goal for it such as Venice above (meaning there's no entry for them on this goal table)
|Date |Region |Country |City |Goal
|:----|:------|:-------|:----|:----
|1/1/2023|NA|America|Seattle|1000
|1/1/2023|NA|America|Los Angeles|800
|1/1/2023|EU|Italy|Rome|2500
|1/2/2023|NA|America|Seattle|1200
|1/2/2023|NA|America|Los Angeles|900
|1/2/2023|EU|Italy|Rome|2200
|1/3/2023|NA|America|Seattle|1500
|1/3/2023|NA|America|Los Angeles|700
|1/3/2023|EU|Italy|Rome|2300

Now what is the best way to join these 2 datasets so that I can show, by every day for each  city/country/region, we have the sales and goal. So like below. Please note that the output will be on a data visualization tool so in the final output, I still need to have the account in there so that people can see sales by accounts if needed.

| Date | Region | Country | City | Sales | Goal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | NA | America | Seattle | 400 | 1000 |
| 1/1/2023 | NA | America | Los Angeles | 400 | 800 |
| 1/1/2023 | EU | Italy | Rome | 0 | 2500 |
| 1/2/2023 | NA | America | Seattle | 0 | 1200 |
| 1/2/2023 | NA | America | Los Angeles | 0 | 900 |
| 1/2/2023 | EU | Italy | Rome | 0 | 2200 |
| 1/3/2023 | NA | America | Seattle | 0 | 1500 |
| 1/3/2023 | NA | America | Los Angeles | 0 | 700 |
| 1/3/2023 | EU | Italy | Rome | 500 | 2300 |
| 1/3/2023 | EU | Italy | Venice | 600 | NULL |

I believe we need to do a full outer join and for each of the first 4 columns, we will use a case when in order to return the value if it has but what is the best practice with different granularities like this? If we join by the region, country, and city columns, then I fear the goal will be aggregated incorrectly if pulled in the data visualization visual

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage multiple conditions on your JOIN clause:

Let's name your first dataset / table as: `daily_sales` and the second dataset /table as `daily_goals`

Then, we can join them using multiple join conditions:

```
SELECT ds.Date, ds.Region, ds.Country, ds.City, ds.Account, ds.Sales, dg.Goal
FROM daily_sales ds
LEFT OUTER JOIN daily_goals dg ON
dg.Region = ds.Region AND dg.Country = ds.Country AND dg.City =  ds.City
```

Now, the result set will show for each `daily_sales` entry (where the ds.Account is present) a Goal associated with the 3 keys used in the join - if there's a correspondence on the `daily_goals` dataset

Some important points:

- If the datasets have big volumes, make sure the keys used in the JOIN clause are either Sort or Distribution Keys on both tables
- Depending on the Data Visualization requirements, using sub-query strategies can help

Comment: Thank you but the thing is if I do left join like this, if there are days that the sales don't happen, the goal won't show here and I don't want that. Please take a look at the 3rd table, date 1/2 and you'll see what I mean